# Subgame Perfect Nash Equilibrium

Tags: game-theory

Army 1, of country 1, must decide whether to attack Army 2, of country 2, which is occupying an
island between the two countries. In the event of an attack, army 2 may fight or retreat over a bridge
to its mainland. Each army prefers to occupy the island than not to occupy it; a fight is the worst
outcome for both armies. Model this situation as an extensive form game and show that army 2 can
increase its payoff by burning the bridge to the mainland, eliminating its option to retreat if attacked.

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

Let A and W be Army 1's options to Attack or Wait. Let D and R be Army 2's options Defend or Retreat. The payoffs for Army 1 might look like the following:

```
    A    W

D   -1   0

R   1    0
```

That is, if Army 1 attacks and Army 2 defends, they fight and Army 1 is down by 1. If Army 1 waits they get no benefit or penalty. If army 1 attacks and army 2 retreats, Army 1 gets a bonus.

Army 2 burning the bridge is a threat that they intend to choose the Defend strategy even though it is weakly dominated by the strategy to retreat. If Army 1 believes this threat, then it is rational for Army 1 not to choose the inefficient solution. Burning the bridge is a mechanism for making the threat credible.